# Terminal spacing between rows and column

Tags: c, macos, unix, ncurses

I am trying to create a snake terminal game with C. I am using `ncurses` to get input from the arrow keys.

I am drawing a simple border with white spaces to get the "map" for the snake.

```
void draw(){
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            if(i == 0 || i == cols-1 || j == 0 || j == rows-1)
                mvaddch(i,j,'#');
            else
                mvaddch(i,j,' ');
        }
    }
    refresh();
}
```

The problem I have is, that the spacing between the columns and rows is different.
Rows and cols are both initialized with the value of 20. So I thought it should be a square. The moving speed changes as well if I move up/down or right/left.

This problem occurs within the terminal.app and iterm2. Is there anyway to change the spacing that it matches?

[image]

Comment: Print two "##" horizontally instead of one. That improves spacing. If that is not good enough then terminal is not your environment.

Comment: okay thank you. thats kind of a bummer, because thats not good enough for me. The moving speed changes aswell if I move up/down or right/left.

Comment: Speed will be aligned with spacing. Just also use two characters horizontally for your snake.

Comment: Or maybe in both cases horizontally one character and a blank gives a smoother impression.

Comment: suggest (using curses) open a user window.  Then navigate it via pixels rather than characters.

Comment: @user3629249 Sounds interesting and might be what OP wants, without the full effort of a graphics approach. Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same number vertically and horizontally of basically non-square "tiles", then the result will be non-square. The same applies for the speed, if you move the same number of steps per second horizontally and vertically, but the length of a step is different, because it is the width and height of a non-square tile, then the perceived speed will be different.

Note that the width of two characters horizontally is much closer to the height of one character vertically than the width of one character.

So, instead of e.g. representing this situation (a square with a snake) with the same number of characters horizontally as vertically

```
##########
#        #
#  ooO   #
#  o     #
#  o     #
#  o     #
#  o     #
#        #
#        #
##########
```

Try this for the same situation, i.e. insert a horizontal blank after each non-blank character, resulting in twice the number of characters horizontally as vertically. Their much longer height than width and the fact that the upper half of most printable characters is largely empty results in an even, much more squarish impression altogether.

```
# # # # # # # # # #
#                 #
#     o o O       #
#     o           #
#     o           #
#     o           #
#     o           #
#                 #
#                 #
# # # # # # # # # #
```

That way you get a much more squarish impression and also some consistent speed horizontally and vertically.

If you do not like the gaps, which are unavoidable vertically and intentional horizontally, then the normal terminal environment is not the right one for your game and you need to change to a graphic environment which allows you pixel-precise control over the result.

Comment: I think the last bit of your answer is correct. It seems that the terminal is not the right environment for me. I think I will be switching over to a graphical environment.